# use python 2.7,bug Decimal type of data is cut off

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

lang : python 2.7
lib : deciaml.Deciaml
database : postgresql
column type: numeric

column have 0.111112222233333444445555566667
Data inserts the Decimal type.

I print out the data through SQL.
However, storing data in variables reduced the length.

example (1)
import : 0.00000111112222233333444445555566666777778888899999
DB  : 0.000001111122222333334444455555
export : 0.00000111112222233

example (2)
import : 0.00000000001111122222333334444455555666667777788888
DB:0.000000000011111222223333344444
export : 0.0000000000111112222233

When data is imported, the data is stored well in the dictionary type, but when the data type of the dictionary is inquired, the float is output.
If you store data in other variables or output only float-type data, the data will be preserved up to 12 digits after 0.

What's the reason for this?
Knowing the cause can solve this problem.

```
    def _compute_current_rate(self):
        date = self._context.get('date') or fields.Datetime.now()
        company_id = self._context.get('company_id') or self.env['res.users']._get_company().id
        # the subquery selects the last rate before 'date' for the given currency/company
        # The column 'rate' in the 'res_current_rate' table is numeric.
        query = """SELECT c.id, (SELECT r.rate FROM res_currency_rate r
                                  WHERE r.currency_id = c.id AND r.name <= %s
                                    AND (r.company_id IS NULL OR r.company_id = %s)
                               ORDER BY r.company_id, r.name DESC
                                  LIMIT 1) AS rate
                   FROM res_currency c
                   WHERE c.id IN %s"""
        self._cr.execute(query, (date, company_id, tuple(self.ids)))
        currency_rates = dict(self._cr.fetchall())
        # {3: 1.1111222223333345e-06}, <type 'float'>
        for currency in self:
            # ex: value '0.00000111112222233', <type 'str'>
            currency.rate = currency_rates.get(currency.id) or 1.0
```

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: I uploaded the part where I get the data from the database.